# Newly installed .NET version doesn't show up in target frameworks

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.7.2

I want do develop a console app for .NET Framework 4.72
I installed the .NET Framework 4.7.2 developer pack.
I restarted the system, opened Visual Studio to create a new project but the :NET Framework 4.7.2 doesn't show up in the target framework options.

What step am I missing?

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using? what project template are you using (be sure you've selected '.net framework' rather than '.net core', for example)

Comment: @TZHX VS2022, C# Console App

Comment: you need to pick the "Console App (.NET Framework)" project template, "Console App" is the artist formerly known as .NET Core, but that now is just .NET

Comment: Why are you using 4.7.1 for a new project, anyway? Use 4.8 when it _needs_ to be .NET Framework, use <s>6.0</s> 7.0 otherwise.